C# XmlDocument LoadXML - Data at the root level is invalid - Remove HIDDEN starting character
I make a HTTP call to service and when I log the response I see below XML (as a string including double quotes). I get the below string as response for external API call which I do not have any control. It seems my xmlstring starts with a HIDDEN characters I need to delete ONLY that HIDDEN character.
"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<PDB>
    <TRANSACTION_TYPE>
        <TYPE>ERROR</TYPE>
    </TRANSACTION_TYPE>
    <ERROR>
        <DESCRIPTION>Bad Input. Please check.</DESCRIPTION>
    </ERROR>
</PDB>"

I tried all solutions shown here as links, but nothing is working for me in C# using .NET Framework 4.5.2.
xml.LoadData - Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1
Why "Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1." for XML Document?
StartsWith change in Windows Server 2012
I am calling an API which I do not have any control over.
After doing string responseData = reader.ReadToEnd();, in responseData, I have string as shown above.
I tried lots of code, but no matter what I try, every time I get this error:

System.Xml.XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 201.
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseRootLevelWhitespace()
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
at System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadDocSequence(XmlDocument parentDoc)
at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
at System.Xml.XmlDocument.LoadXml(String xml)

This is sample code I wrote
  using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse())
  {
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Created)
    {
      using (var respStream = response.GetResponseStream())
      {
        using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(respStream, true))
         {
           string responseData = reader.ReadToEnd(); 
           if (responseData.Contains(@"<TYPE>ERROR</TYPE>"))
           {
             string _byteOrderMarkUtf8 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble());
              if (responseData.StartsWith(_byteOrderMarkUtf8, StringComparison.Ordinal))
               {
                 log.DebugFormat("responseData starts with HIDDEN : {0}", _byteOrderMarkUtf8); // in my logs I see ? character
                 **// it seems I have ? at start of my string and need to delete this only. But when I try to delete first character it deletes double quote.
               }                
             XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
             doc.LoadXml(responseData);
            }
          }
      }
   }
}

UPDATE SOLUTION
I took the route of get the text between <PDB> and </PBD> and use that to LoadXml() like below
using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(respStream, true))
{
  
  string responseData = reader.ReadToEnd(); 
  if (responseData.Contains(@"<TYPE>ERROR</TYPE>"))
  {
    int pFrom = responseData.IndexOf("<PDB>");
    int pTo = responseData.LastIndexOf("</PDB>");

    string subresponseData = responseData.Substring(pFrom, (pTo - pFrom) + "</PDB>".Length);
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(subresponseData);
  }
}


Please can you provide an example which reproduces the error with hardcoded data rather than via an HTTP response? Otherwise we're not going to be able to reproduce it.

As I explained in my question, I provided the hard coded string which is in xml format and I want to use LoadXml() method. Forget about HTTP calls. Let me update the question.

Remove the double quotes from your XML string and it simply gets parsed.

@CetinBasoz - sorry I didnot understand your comment of removing double quotes. I updated the question to make it simple.

It is dead simple really, I have provided a complete code that you could directly run on Linqpad below.

@CetinBasoz - looking at it

Your example works just fine

@Ziggler What is the mystery hidden character? You could look at the bytes of the string to see what is not as expected.

Since your last edit the example does not compile, so your issue is not reproducible. Check the actual content of responseData in the debugger.

What is the result of ((int)responseData[0]).ToString("X") and ((int)responseData[1]).ToString("X")

Remove the double quotes from your XML string and it simply gets parsed. ie:
void Main()
{
    XDocument.Parse(myxml).Dump();
}


static readonly string myxml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><PDB><TRANSACTION_TYPE><TYPE>ERROR</TYPE></TRANSACTION_TYPE><ERROR><DESCRIPTION>Bad Input. Please check.</DESCRIPTION></ERROR></PDB>";

You can paste and run this as is in LinqPad (which has a free version). Output is displayed as:
<PDB>
  <TRANSACTION_TYPE>
    <TYPE>ERROR</TYPE>
  </TRANSACTION_TYPE>
  <ERROR>
    <DESCRIPTION>Bad Input. Please check.</DESCRIPTION>
  </ERROR>
</PDB>


I cannot find Dump() method for XDocument in System.Linq.Xml in .NET 4.5.2. I am looking into this more

I tried XDocument.Parse(myxml) but still same error. It seems my xmlString starts with HIDDEN character and I need to remove that HIDDEN characters. I will update my question

@Ziggler, you are not reading what I wrote. Dump is built-in in LinqPad. You can copy paste and run this code in LinqPad. If you wouldn't use LinqPad for any reason (I can't think of one), then instead of Dump() you can check the result with something else. ie: Console.WriteLine. It works and the output is as the above. In your sample there were extra quotes. An XML cannot start with a quotes.

Thanks. I am able to solve my issue. Updating my question with solution

@Ziggler, you don't need to update your question. You have solution above.

XDocument.Parse(myxml) didnot solve my issue. Thanks @Cetin Basoz

@Ziggler why it didn't? Above sample clearly shows you needed to remove extra quotes.
